# Using PC as a virtual USB flash storage device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, connection-sharing

I have a Linux server that has an application installed which writes its logs to a connected USB flash drive. I need to have a constant access to these logs which means I cannot unplug the USB flash, download the logs to another PC and plug it back in. I have no other access to the Linux server so I cannot modify any configuration on it, which probably leaves me with only one solution: try to connect another PC instead of the flash drive with a USB adapter and trick the Linux server into believing that the PC is flash drive (virtual). I have searched the net and found adapters for connecting two or more PCs together but most of them (if not all) use custom software to transfer data between the computers and I assume they do so without creating a virtual usb mass storage device. Besides I am unable to write that software to a Linux machine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I am seeking a solution to a very similar problem. Although I haven't tested this yet, I think it might be possible to work around this using ["Wireless USB Drives" devices](https://www.premiumusb.com/blog/what-are-wireless-usb-drives) like [ezShare](https://www.newegg.com/p/0DS-01AR-004T0) or perhaps [SanDisk Connect](https://www.sandisk.com/goto/connect).

Some details that aren't yet clear to me are:

- Does the data producing device need to be aware / have special support to make it work? This would be a show-stopper in my case as I have no control over that part.
- Does the consuming device need special software to access the data wirelessly or does it follow some standards? This seems to vary by device/technology/solution.
- Can the data be read wirelessly/remotely while the storage file system is mounted / being written to by the data producing device?

Another solution path that I am pursuing is to use a [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.org/) device in "[USB gadget](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/driver-api/usb/gadget.html)" mode. It looks like some others have already published examples demonstrating how to make the device act like a USB mass storage device:
https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=243966&sid=c6f777e0e7baada2ceb2b91da883d17f
https://support.speedify.com/article/576-raspberry-pi-speedify-usb-gadget
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100583/where-is-the-usb2-otg-port-on-the-rpi-4-model-b-located

Answer (score 0):

What about ssh transfer to another computer? If you have the need access this will be a good variant. See this topic

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to ssh server

Comment: Can you tell what exactly access you have to server(except the flash drive if you have at all), that will be more easy to help you

Comment: Just the flash drive. I would write in the original post if any other :)